# regex # Replace square brackets to braces,but don't replace if text is in this format [text][text2]

Tags: regex, notepad++

First of all,sorry if the title is 'messed up' and you can't really understand if that well..i'm not that good with titles.

I'm trying to make a regex match (first time using complex regex),that replaces [ with { and ] with } but i have a problem.. my script is something like this

```
 new asd[MAX_PLAYERS];

 asd[player] = 1;
 if(asd[player] >= 1)

 other[player][index] = 1;
```

and i'm trying to only replace the variables that only have one match of [text],so that the code above will become

```
 new asd{MAX_PLAYERS};

 asd{player} = 1;
 if(asd{player} >= 1)

 other[player][index] = 1;
```

I tried using [[a-zA-Z_]*] but it matches everything that's in brackets,and it would of been good if my script wasn't 25k lines long.
I tried using [[a-zA-Z_]*] |[[a-zA-Z_]*]; which kinda works but not,because it still matches the [index]
And i also tried something to not match the lines that have ] in front of [ , but i failed horribly.

BTW - I'm using Notepad++

Comment: What language are you using regex with?

Comment: Not a language,i'm using notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are one way to do it.

Pattern: `(?<!\])\[(\w+)](?!\[)`

Replacement: `{$1}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust solution that would work on regex101.com, but unsure if notepad++ can handle it.

`/(?:\[[^]]+\]){2}\K|\[([^\]]+)\]/g`

replace with `{\1}`

http://regex101.com/r/wE5mG5